# How could a root app call APIs with signature-level protected permission

Tags: android, root, android-permissions

Android 4.2 introduced multiple user support, that involves some existent internal APIs now require new permissions called `INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS` and `INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL`.

The latter one is declared as

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:label="@string/permlab_interactAcrossUsersFull"
        android:description="@string/permdesc_interactAcrossUsersFull" />
```

That means only apps signed with same signature as the platform (ROM) can use this permission.

I'd like to know if I cannot sign my app with platform signature, is there any way under root conditions can achieve the same purpose?

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access, you can install your apk in /system/app (instead of /data/app). This should cause your app to qualify as "signatureOrSystem" and you should be given the permission.

Comment: Sorry, but I was asking for "signature"-only permission.

Comment: It still won't grant the signature level permissions